# How Can I Tell If Another Message Is Pending In A TCP Connection

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a sending application that uses TCP to send files. Sometimes these files contain one message, and other times the file may contain multiple messages. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the Sending application's code.

I am working on editing legacy code to receive these messages. I have managed to get the legacy application to accept a file when there is a single message sent. However, since I disconnect the socket after receiving a single message, the Sender gives a disconnect error.

I wrote a small process to help determine whether there was another message. If it worked, I was going to incorporate it into the code, but I had mixed results:

```
Dim check(1) As Byte
If (handler.Receive(check, SocketFlags.Peek) > 0) Then
   Dim bytesRec As Integer
   ReDim bytes(1024)
   bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes)
End If
```

If there is another message being sent, this will detect it. However, if the file only has a single message, it locks up on Receive until I send another file, and then it is accepted.

Is there a way to tell if there is another message pending that will not lock up if the stream is empty?

I won't post all of the code for accepting the message, as it is a legacy rat's nest, but the general idea is below:

```
s2 = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
handler = s2.EndAccept(ar)
bytes = New Byte(1024) {}
Dim bytesRec As Integer = handler.Receive(bytes)
' Send Ack/Nak.  
numAckBytesSent = handler.Send(myByte)
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Socket.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx) can be used as a quick way of polling a socket for readability. Pass in a timeout of 0 seconds, and the socket in question in the readability list, and it will simply check and report back immediately.

Two other options might be to set [`Socket.ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx) on your socket, or make the socket non-blocking using [`Socket.Blocking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking.aspx), so that you can find out (as part of the `Receive` call) whether there is incoming data. These look a bit inconvenient to do in .NET, though, as they throw exceptions rather than simply returning a value, which might make the code a little longer.

Comment: I did a quick test, and Socket.Select seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep reading. If there is nothing left you will get an end-of-stream indication of some kind, depending on your API.